# How to safely handle API password from front-end web client side to Web API?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, frontend, passwords, authorization

The situation is that there is a backend Web API which requires the front-end page caller provides  the authorization data (username and password). And I need to write a front-end web client code to be the Web API caller. (It's a general usage no matter what which language is)

The Web API has only provides the Basic Authorization, no other ways to do it like token or something else.

If I directly wrote the username and password as plain text on the client side code, the user could see these plain text in the source code from browser easily.

I wonder what is the best practice to handle these authorization data in front-end client side page?

Thanks

Comment: plain text is common practice.. there's no need in encrypting this data on the client side as it stays on the client. you do still need to store atleast a token-like cookie och auth data in local storage to keep the user logged in and not reauthorize on each page navigation or reload

Comment: The username and password are for access to the API to make calls so you do not want the user to be able to see it as they are private to you. Am I correct in this assumption?

Comment: @JayHales Yes. The Web API is developed a few years ago, so it only provide Basic Authorization. Even I know there is a better authorization machinima, but I cannot make them change. So, that's what I want to know, how to avoid the user to see this API password as plain text if I need to make a call just from the client side with JavaScript.  My assumption is that this is a separation of front-end and backend architecture. There is no middle tier here.

Comment: Unless you have access to the source code of the API and can make changes  I doubt there is a solution here. If something is stored on a clients machine there is no way of stopping them from accessing it. You can obfuscate and slow them down but if someone wants it enough they will be able to get access to it.

Comment: Ultimately, they could look at the network traffic leaving their machine and see the plaintext, which *must* be plaintext by that point for the server to receive it in the correct format. Obviously, an extreme case but it shows the danger.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. As your comment, If the Web API cannot be modified, there is no perfect way to protect the password even using some obfuscate methods.

Comment: You could set up another server to sit in the middle: your client makes a request to a server you own, that server has the username and password stored which is safe as you are in full control. Your server then makes a request to the Web API and sends the result back to the original client. Of course, this isn't exactly a very elegant front end solution but it would be secure.

Comment: I've added an answer to the question just to wrap everything up and help anyone else who comes across this post. Feel free to mark it as the correct answer if you feel it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be impossible for you to hide plaintext details leaving a clients machine as there are many places they would be able to intercept it. One solution would be to set up a server in the middle which acts as a proxy between your client and the API. You can have whatever authentication you like on the middle server and you can store your details there safely.